# VM starts with system disk in read-only mode

Tags: read-only

My vm starts with the system disk in read-only mode, so system can't load anything properly. The instance was created with the disk of and old vm, but in the instance properties disk is "boot, read/write" mode.

Server responds to ping, and I can connect by using FTP. Files are there but a lot of processes are not loaded as they should be.

Any tip for solving this issue?

Comment: It sounds a little like you might suffer from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What makes you say the disk is in read-only mode, and what exact errors are you seeing? There isn't a fundamental issue with the boot/system disk being read-only, so long as the system is configured accordingly. I think it might help get you some answers if you could expand a little on the issues you see with your processes, and provided a bit more background on how you moved your disk to a new VM.

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post self-answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue. If not, you can provide further information as @iwaseatenbyagrue suggested to further troubleshooting.

Comment: Is there a filesystem error inside the VM file?

Answer (score 1):

The only typical scenario where a disk get mounted as read only is when the disk is [attached to multiple VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#can_i_attach_my_persistent_disk_to_more_than_one_instance). You might want to check the [FS consistency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system) and the information given by  [dmesg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105793/why-has-my-file-system-turned-read-only-after-updates). 
Another place to have a look is the content of [/etc/fstab](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-do-i-create-a-read-only-bind-mount-in-fstab-778248) just in case the default file was re-written and is mounting the disk as read only.